# How to write to a file in an organized manner?

Tags: python, text-files

I have this code:

```
file = open('scores.txt','w')
playerscores = []
playernames = [['A'],['B'],['C'],['D'],['E'],['F']]   
for y in range(6):
    for z in range(5):
            print("Enter score from Judge",z+1,"for couple ",playernames[0+y],"in round 1:")
            playerscores.append(int(input()))    
MY_LIST = str(playerscores)
for_every = 4
```

Essentially, I want to write to the file by making the the following index positions print on a new line

```
playerscore[0:6]
playerscore[7:13]
```

etc

So it would look like:

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

and not `[1,1,1,1,1,1]`

I need to do this so when i do

```
file = open('filename','r')
```

and call a position, it is easily given out.

Comment: anyone come up with a solution?

Comment: Why are you converting the strings you get from `input()` into integers? Do you intend to do arithmetic with them later on in the program?

Comment: You could just save the input strings for the current row into a list, and then after the `for z` loop finishes join them into a single string (using the technique shown in coder's answer), so you can write the data for that row to the file.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes will use later for arithmetics

Comment: @PM2Ring can you show me what you meant by saving the strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that does what you want, although it gets its data from my `get_data()` function instead of from `input()`. This makes the code easier to test. But you can easily replace the `get_data()` call with `input()` once you've finished developing the program.

The key idea is that as well as saving the integer version of the input data to `playerscores` we also save it in its original string form in a separate list named `row`. So when we've finished reading the data for a given row we can easily save it to the file. This is simpler than trying to split the data up from `playerscores` and converting it back into strings.

```
from random import seed, randrange

# Seed the randomizer
seed(42)

# Make some fake data, to simulate user input.
# Print & return a random number from 1 to 5, in string form
def get_data():
    n = str(randrange(1, 6))
    print(n)
    return n

playernames = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

numjudges = 5

playerscores = []
scoresfile = open('scores.txt', 'w')

for players in playernames:
    row = []
    for z in range(1, numjudges + 1):
        print("Enter score from Judge", z, "for couple ", players, "in round 1:")
        data = get_data()
        playerscores.append(int(data))
        row.append(data)
    scoresfile.write(','.join(row) + '\n')
    print()
scoresfile.close()
```

**typical output**

```
Enter score from Judge 1 for couple  A in round 1:
1
Enter score from Judge 2 for couple  A in round 1:
1
Enter score from Judge 3 for couple  A in round 1:
3
Enter score from Judge 4 for couple  A in round 1:
2
Enter score from Judge 5 for couple  A in round 1:
2

Enter score from Judge 1 for couple  B in round 1:
2
Enter score from Judge 2 for couple  B in round 1:
1
Enter score from Judge 3 for couple  B in round 1:
5
Enter score from Judge 4 for couple  B in round 1:
1
Enter score from Judge 5 for couple  B in round 1:
5

Enter score from Judge 1 for couple  C in round 1:
4
Enter score from Judge 2 for couple  C in round 1:
1
Enter score from Judge 3 for couple  C in round 1:
1
Enter score from Judge 4 for couple  C in round 1:
1
Enter score from Judge 5 for couple  C in round 1:
2

Enter score from Judge 1 for couple  D in round 1:
2
Enter score from Judge 2 for couple  D in round 1:
5
Enter score from Judge 3 for couple  D in round 1:
5
Enter score from Judge 4 for couple  D in round 1:
1
Enter score from Judge 5 for couple  D in round 1:
5

Enter score from Judge 1 for couple  E in round 1:
2
Enter score from Judge 2 for couple  E in round 1:
5
Enter score from Judge 3 for couple  E in round 1:
4
Enter score from Judge 4 for couple  E in round 1:
2
Enter score from Judge 5 for couple  E in round 1:
4

Enter score from Judge 1 for couple  F in round 1:
5
Enter score from Judge 2 for couple  F in round 1:
3
Enter score from Judge 3 for couple  F in round 1:
1
Enter score from Judge 4 for couple  F in round 1:
2
Enter score from Judge 5 for couple  F in round 1:
4
```

**contents of scores.txt**

```
1,1,3,2,2
2,1,5,1,5
4,1,1,1,2
2,5,5,1,5
2,5,4,2,4
5,3,1,2,4
```

Comment: appreciate it. its so much more easier now.

Comment: @PM2Ring No worries, here's an +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you are looking for something like this:

```
l = [4,3,2,5,6,4,6]
# split l in chunks -> e.g. [[4,3,2], [5,6,4,6]] 
chunks = [[4,3,2], [5,6,4,6]]

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f: 
    for i,chunk in enumerate(chunks):
        if i!=0:
            f.write('\n'+','.join(str(i) for i in chunk))
        else:
            f.write(','.join(str(i) for i in chunk))

# read data back in ls as integers
ls = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        ls += map(int,line.split(','))

print ls
```

Comment: thank you works, but how about would i go so that the index positions are on separate lines like \n

Comment: @Mahir what do you mean ? write `1`'s vertically instead of horizontally ?

Comment: no like for example if i did `playerscores = [4,3,2,5,6,4,6]` and i wanted `playerscores[0:3]` to be on a separate line from `playerscores[4:5]`

Comment: The data for each row (each `y` value) needs to be written to the file on a separate line.

Comment: thank you! but could you add a for loop so it puts to new line `[0:5] [6:10]` so is equal and more simplified @coder

Comment: Updated the answer!

Comment: sorry im new to this. @PM2Ring approved

Comment: @Mahir no worries ! PM2Ring's answer is great for what you are trying to do!

Comment: @PM2Ring how would i access an array (playerscores) in another function?

Comment: @Mahir The usual way is to return the `playerscores` list from the function that created it, and then pass it in as an argument to the other function.

Comment: but getting an error when doing so; `TypeError: round2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'playerscores'` @PM2Ring

Comment: @somebrick Ok. I see why you're asking a new question now. :) So put some relevant code in the new question. We need a [mcve] that focuses on this problem of passing a list from one function to another.